# Confusing "multiple properties with the same name in strict mode" error message

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

## Background

Inside my Angular2 project, I have a file named `random.metadata.ts`, which contains this code:

```js
import {
    Component,
    ChangeDetectionStrategy,
    AnimationEntryMetadata,
    ViewEncapsulation,
    Type
} from '@angular/core';

export interface RandomInterface {
    configurationUrl?: string;
    changeDetection?: ChangeDetectionStrategy;
    viewProviders?: any[];
    moduleId?: string;
    templateUrl?: string;
    template?: string;
    styleUrls?: string[];
    styles?: string[];
    animations?: AnimationEntryMetadata[];
    interpolation?: [string, string];
    entryComponents?: Array<Type<any> | any[]>;
    properties?: string[];
    inputs?: string[];
    events?: string[];
    outputs?: string[];
    host?: {
        [key: string]: string;
    };
    exportAs?: string;
    queries?: {
        [key: string]: any;
    };
}

export class RandomMetadata extends Component implements RandomInterface {
    constructor({configurationUrl, inputs, outputs, host, exportAs, moduleId,
        viewProviders, changeDetection = ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default,
        queries, templateUrl, template, styleUrls, styles, animations,
        interpolation, entryComponents}: RandomInterface = {}) {

        super({
            template: template,
            inputs: inputs,
            outputs: outputs,
            templateUrl: templateUrl,
            host: host,
            exportAs: exportAs,
            moduleId: moduleId,
            providers: providers,
            viewProviders: viewProviders,
            changeDetection: changeDetection,
            queries: queries,
            styleUrls: styleUrls,
            styles: styles,
            animations: animations,
            encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native,
            interpolation: interpolation,
            entryComponents: entryComponents
        });
    }
}
```

Also, my `tsconfig.json` is written as follows

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "declaration": true,
        "baseUrl": "src/"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ],
     "include": [
        "node_modules/**/*.d.ts",
        "typings-custom/**/*.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

## Problem

When I try to compile the whole project, what I get is these two errors.

> ERROR in [default] random.metadata.ts:44:12
> An object literal cannot have multiple properties with the same name in strict mode.
>
> ERROR in [default] random.metadata.ts:44:12
> Duplicate identifier 'template'.

As you can see, my ECMAScript target version is defined as es6, hence it should not yield this specific syntax error.

> In ECMAScript 5 strict mode code, duplicate property names were considered a SyntaxError.  With the introduction of computed property names making duplication possible at runtime, ECMAScript 2015 has removed this restriction. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)

Besides that, the object literal does not have a duplicated `template` property. It does have a `templateUrl` property, which is the line where the error appears.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm getting the same error without any custom code, if I supply both `styles` and `styleUrls` in an Angular 2 `@Component`. So my first guess would be it's not your own code. By the way: in the end this gets me transpiled client side JavaScript that runs fine; I only get the message in WebStorm IDE, not in the browser.

Comment: Note that, for templates, [the code states](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/core/src/metadata/directives.ts#L559-L571) "Only one of `templateUrl` or `template` can be defined per Component.", so I'm quite sure Angular somehow maps both to the same property. It amazes me that the compiler seems to detect that when validating or transpiling though...